# getting a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, queue

I'm creating a generic box with a template. Basically something like a queue or linked list. I keep getting a SIGSEGV for some reason and I can't figure it out. I take in an integer or a string from the user in main and then the constructor makes allocates memory for the generic box to exist, then using function inert_First (there are a lot more functions like insert_Mid, insert_last, delete_Mid etc) and it keeps telling me I'm accessing wrong memory but I don't know where ?

this is the class

```
template<class T>
class g_Box
{
    int first,mid,last;
    int no_Of_Ele;
    int capacity;
    T *ele;
public:

    g_Box();
    g_Box(int);
    void insert_First(T);
};
```

this is the constructor

```
template<class T>
g_Box<T>::g_Box(){
    first=-1, last=-1, mid=-1;
    no_Of_Ele=0;
    capacity=10;
    T *ele = new T[capacity];
}

template<class T>
g_Box<T>::g_Box(int a){
    first=-1, last=-1, mid=-1;
    no_Of_Ele=0;
    capacity=a;
    T *ele = new T[capacity];
}
```

This is the insert_First

```
template<class T>
void g_Box<T>::insert_First(T a){
    if(isFull()){
        cout<<"The box is full";
    }
    else if(isEmpty()){
        first=0; last=0; mid=(first+last)/2;
        ele[0]=a;
        no_Of_Ele++;
    }
    else{
        T *ele2 = new T[capacity];
        //T ele2[capacity];
        for(int i=0; i<no_Of_Ele; i++){
            ele2[i]=ele[i];
        }
        for(int i=0; i<no_Of_Ele; i++){
            ele[i+1]=ele2[i];
        }
        ele[first]=a;
        last++;
        mid=(first+last)/2;
        no_Of_Ele++;
        delete[] ele2;
    }
}
```

and this is the main

```
int main()
{
    g_Box<int> g;
    int data;
    cin>>data
    g.insert_First(data);
}
```

Comment: You could run it in a debugger and see where the crash is. I can't since `isFull` and `isEmpty` are missing.

Comment: The statement `T *ele = new T[capacity];` that is in your constuctors does not affect the member of the class named `ele`.   In fact, it creates a new - unrelated - variable of automatic storage duration which ceases to exist once the constructor returns.   The member named `ele` is never initialised, and certainly will not somehow - magically - point at the dynamically allocated array. In subsequently called member function, the `ele` member is used, despite never being initialised - hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for helping but I just had to initialise my pointer correctly. The issue is solved.